# Is there a name for relations with this property, and the category of them?

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, type-theory

The following math.stackexchange question asked whether there is a name for a certain sort of relation.  I have become interested in the question, and no one suggested a name there, so I am asking here instead.  Furthermore I would be interested in the name of the category of such relations.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391108/is-there-a-name-for-relations-with-this-property

I repeat the specification from the above link.  The relations are those of the form $\rho : X \rightarrow Y$ such that for all $x,x' \in X$ and all $y,y' \in Y$ we have that the following conditions

$$xy \in \rho$$ $$x'y \in \rho$$ $$xy' \in \rho$$ imply that $$x'y' \in \rho$$

By "category of such relations" I mean the category whose objects are such relations $\rho : X_\rho \rightarrow Y_\rho$, and whose morphisms are pairs of functions $(f_X : X_\rho \to X_{\rho'}, \,\, f_Y : Y_\rho \to Y_{\rho'})$ that preserve relatedness, i.e. $xy \in \rho \Rightarrow f_X(x)f_Y(y) \in \rho'$.

I am considering these concepts in the context of John Reynold's work on relational parametricity in type theory.

Comment: Whatever they might be called, this looks like an interesting notion. Remark that functions and opposites of functions form such relations. Also remark that the condition is equivalent to saying $\rho = \rho \rho^{op} \rho$ (literally the condition is saying "$\geq$", but "$\leq$" happens to be true for any relation $\rho$). I can't locate my copy of Categories, Allegories to see if Freyd-Scedrov introduce this notion, but I am vaguely reminded of von Neumann regular elements.

Comment: Interesting, Todd.  Indeed operator theory might be a good place to look for an analogy.  Perhaps the correct condition there would be $\rho = \rho\rho^*\rho$, where $\rho^*$ is the adjoint of $\rho$.  This class would contain the orthogonal operators, for example.

Comment: I've just posted an answer to the MSE question, but note that such relations are also called *difunctional* relations. In the category of sets, or any pretopos, they coincide with pullbacks, see for example http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/27/1/27-01abs.html

Comment: Robert Harper, in "Reynolds’s Parametricity Theorem, Directly" calls these "zig-zag complete" binary relations (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/chtt/pdfs/reynolds.pdf).

Comment: The earliest reference I know of to such relations related to parametricity is "Internalizing Relational Parametricity in the Extensional Calculus of Constructions" by Krishnaswami and Dreyer (2013).

Answer (score 4):

The set of all relations $\alpha\subset X\times Y$ is a **semiheap** with respect to the ternary operation $[\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3]=\alpha_1\alpha_2^{-1}\alpha_3$ ($\alpha^{-1}$ is $\alpha^{*}$in notation of **Tom Ellis** and $\alpha^{op}$ by **Todd Trimble**). Your relation yields $[\rho,\rho,\rho]=\rho$ and is called an **idempotent** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiheap).

Comment: @ Todd Trimble: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across such relations in the past, and (in my head) have referred to them as *jigsaw* relations. The idea is probably best conveyed in the form of a picture, but I will try to explain my thinking.

Let $\rho\colon X\to Y$ be a relation arising from jigsaw pieces in the following way. Think of the elements of $X$ as jigsaw pieces with a 'tab' sticking out of the right edge, the elements of $Y$ as jigsaw pieces with a 'hole' in the left edge, and $xy\in\rho$ as meaning "the tab of $x$ fits exactly into the hole of $y$".

**Claim**: such a relation satisfies $xy,x'y,xy'\in\rho\implies x'y'\in\rho$.

**Proof**: if $xy\in\rho$ and $x'y\in\rho$ then the tab of $x'$ must be identical to the tab of $x$ (because they both fit exactly into the hole of $y$), so if $xy'\in\rho$ as well then the tab of $x'$ fits exactly into the hole of $y'$ because the tab of $x$ does. That is, $x'y'\in\rho$ follows
from the other three conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I like the jigsaw analogy.  It seems to fit perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

These have probably been invented many times, but they are most typically called [difunctional relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogeneous_relation#Difunctional).  They were introduced and named that by Jacques Riguet in 1948, [Relations binaires, fermetures, correspondances de Galois](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1948__76__114_0.pdf).

A nice paper on them is Lambek's [Goursat's Theorem and the Zassenhaus Lemma](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/goursats-theorem-and-the-zassenhaus-lemma/4CA706FD7776D9E6B89C1E9D94C282B0), which shows that when you have a Mal'cev term (which includes groups, rings, Lie algebras, etc.) that every relation is difunctional, and you can use that to give a unified proof of the Jordan-Hölder theorem.  (The unified proof is not new with that paper, but it shows how to effectively use difunctionality.)